# Problem with a Galois extension

Tags: galois-theory

How can i prove that Q(a,b) is a Galois extension and that its Galois group is of order 6, if a is a root of the cubic that is not 1 and b is the cubic root of 2?

Can you give me a little hint for the proof only that a finite extension (the Galois extension),  i have the rest of the problem.

Comment: What is *the* cubic that is not one?

Comment: any of the other two in complex numbers.

Comment: I think Julio is trying to say that $a$ is one of the nontrivial cube roots of $1$. (The phrase "root of the cubic" does not at all communicate this, unfortunately.)

Comment: yes, a is nontrivial

Comment: Julio, you forgot to tell that $a$ is a cubic root of $1$ as opposed to, say a cubic root of $8$ or $216$ or $5$ or ...

Comment: I`m sorry, i forgot that. a is a cubic root of 1, that isn`t the trivial one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all argue that: since $\mathbb{Q}(a)/\mathbb{Q}$ is an extension of degree 3 and $\mathbb{Q}(b)/\mathbb{Q}(a)$ is of degree 2 we have $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)/\mathbb{Q}$ is a degree 6 extension.
Moreover $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ is the splitting field of $f(x)=x^3-2$.

Comment: ok, thank´s but, that´s the part that i have

Comment: @Julio So what are you missing?

Comment: the part of the finiteness